# How do I allow two way databinding in my UWP Application with XAML/C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This data binding has me stumped. I am trying to bind the text of a button to the text of my players life. I followed some other articles and thought I had it down, app runs but the button text remains blank. Here is my XAML:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:Player x:Name="PlayerCur"></local:Player>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Background="#FFFFFFFF">
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,181,0">
<TextBlock x:Name="LifeTitle" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Life" Height="56" Width="139"/>
        <Button Name="Life" Content="{Binding PlayerLife}" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="126" Width="139">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reset Life" Click="Reset_Life_Click"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Name="lAdd" Text="Heal"   >
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="lAddone" Text="+1" Click="Add_OneL_Click"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="lAddfive" Text="+5"  Click="Add_FiveL_Click"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="lAddten" Text="+10" Click="Add_TenL_Click"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Name="lSubtract" Text="Deal Damage">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="lSubone" Text="-1" Click="Sub_OneL_Click"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="lSubthree" Text="-5" Click="Sub_FiveL_Click"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="lSubfive" Text="-10" Click="Sub_TenL_Click"/>
                    </MenuFlyoutSubItem>


                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator></MenuFlyoutSeparator>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the Player Class:

```
    namespace App1.Classes
    {
        public class Player: INotifyPropertyChanged
       {
    private string _PlayerLife;
    private string _PlayerPoison;
    private int _life = 20;
    private int _poison = 0;
    public string PlayerLife
    {
        get { return _PlayerLife; }

    }
    public string PlayerPoison
    {
        get { return _PlayerPoison; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public void reset(int destination)
    {
        if(destination==0)
        {
            _life = 20;
            OnPropertyChanged("Life");
        }
        else if(destination==1)
        {
            _poison = 0;
            OnPropertyChanged("Poison");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public void incrementer(int destination,int modifier)
    {
        if(destination==0)
        {
            _life = _life + modifier;
            _PlayerLife = _life.ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged("life");
        }
        else if(destination==1)
        {
            _poison = _poison + modifier;
            _PlayerPoison = _poison.ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged("poison");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I feel like the issue is with my class not notifying the XAML when the life and poison change.

Any suggestions/pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real Simple.
Just enter `Content="{Binding PlayerLife, **Mode=TwoWay**}"`
(Those asterisks are just there to indicate new code, don't actually put them in)

Answer (score 1):

The OnPropertyChanged() methods are not correct as they need to match the name of the properties exactly.  The properties are PlayerLife and PlayerPoison but your OnPropertyChanged calls use "Life", "Poison", "life" and "poison".  Try

```
OnPropertyChange(nameof(PlayerLife));
```